# Can't retrieve pdf file from SQL

Tags: c#, .net

For some reason, it doesn't recognize the file no matter what, I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong...

```
Stream fs = fuBOMUpload.PostedFile.InputStream;
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
string fileDesc = fuBOMUpload.PostedFile.FileName;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contentType", 
fuBOMUpload.PostedFile.ContentType);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileName", fileDesc);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", bytes);
```

This is how i save file, to download i do it like this

```
 protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string idColaborador = GridFiles.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text; 

            byte[] bytes;
            string fileName;
            string contentType;
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FolhaRegisto_ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spDados"))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action","SELECTALL");
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdColaborador", idColaborador);
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();

                    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        sdr.Read();
                        bytes = (byte[])sdr["Ficheiro"];
                        fileName = sdr["DescricaoDados"].ToString();
                        contentType = sdr["TipoFicheiro"].ToString();

                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
            }

            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ".pdf");
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
```

Even if i added the .pdf extension it won't open the file like it was corrupted or something but I'm saving all the bytes so i don't know what is wrong

Comment: Its not quite clear what you're doing or where the problem is. It looks like you're uploading a file via http, storing that in a SQL database, then later retrieving that file and sending it back down via http? If the file is corrupt at the last stage you need to trace it backwards to find out where its getting corrupt. What type of sql column are you putting the data into? Have you confirmed the upload works correctly?

Comment: Yes it's saving correctly in SQL in a binary with 2MB size. Also this is just some part of the code because the rest doesn't matter much. I upload a file in a form and store it in SQL and must be PDF. Later I print the file name in a gridview with download option